# Swig #define error when generating wrappers from interface file

Tags: java, c++, swig

I am creating wrappers for thirdparty code which include #define like below and it gives error like below and swig gives Error: Syntax error in input(3). I have also tried to copy below constants inside interface file but no luck.

```
#ifndef DCMTK_DECL_EXPORT
#define DCMTK_DECL_EXPORT
#endif

#ifndef DCMTK_DECL_IMPORT
#define DCMTK_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#ifdef dcmdata_EXPORTS
#define DCMTK_DCMDATA_EXPORT DCMTK_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define DCMTK_DCMDATA_EXPORT DCMTK_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear without more information, but my crystal ball think you might be on Windows, and  that `DCMTK_DECL_EXPORT` is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)`.  SWIG doesn't understand the Windows `__declspec` statement, but will ignore it correctly if you `%include <windows.i>` in the SWIG interface file.